# Rails 4 Inner Join On Same Table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, join

In a Rails 4 app I have the following associations :

```
User has_many :bookings
Booking belongs_to :client, class_name: "User"
```

I am trying to make a JOIN through tables to grab the Booking AND the CLIENT:

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN bookings on users.id = bookings.user_id").joins("INNER JOIN users on bookings.client_id = users.id")
```

Which returns:

```
PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR:  table name "users" specified more than once
```

Is there a solution to fetch the 2 associations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN bookings on users.id = bookings.user_id").joins("INNER JOIN users AS bookings_user on bookings.client_id = bookings_user.id")
```

Note the `users AS bookings_user`